# Is there a Google Search Appliance image available for testing?

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I have been asked to adapt some web forms from using Google Site Search to GSA. The target server is locked down in such a way that I can't easily test functionality. I was therefore wondering if there is a way to emulate a Google Search Appliance in a a local development environment?

Would the [Onebox emulator](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/download/downloadsdk.html) provide me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old VMWare image [available](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://dl.google.com/vgsa/vgsa_20081028.7z&usg=AFQjCNE5u67Nl_-IA83ho--XjfYxcvTnSw) but it has not been updated since 2008.